# Change the image of a specific button

Tags: swift

This is the first app I'm writing so this could be an easy question.
I want to delete the image of a button with a tag.
What I have is this line of code:

```
.setImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: UIControlState())
```

But what do I have to write in front of this line so I can "talk" to specific buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that line will fail (or if it succeeds, it will succeed only accidentally).

Second: to talk to a specific button, you need to have configured an *outlet* (`IBOutlet`) both in your code and in the storyboard, so that you can refer to the button by means of a variable name.

Comment: Stating why that line will fail may be a good addition to your answer

Comment: @milo526 Feel free to add an answer that explains it. It isn't what the OP asked so I didn't bother to elucidate. If the OP is going to encounter an issue, that will happen in its own good time.